# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Nvidia 435.21 Linux stable drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Is it possible to use with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS -Nvidia 435.21 Linux stable drivers now? With this driver is possible now to use Nvidia Optimus for the first time now. 
I see only 430 drivers from info here, but I need 435.21 for Mate desktop and-mate-optimus utility.
"The latest version of ‘mate-optimus’ is the 19.10.x series targeted at Ubuntu 19.10. "
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/09/nvidia-optimus-linux-switching-applet 
I have Quadro K2100M card and Intel HD4600 with Optimus(Dell Precision M4800)